# textblob.exceptions.NotTranslated: Translation API returned the input string unchanged

Tags: textblob

I am trying to translate non-english texts into english via textblob. I read documentation and trying to handle possible exceptions as below:

```
txt=" "
for word in text.split():
    try:
        w=TextBlob(word)
        w=w.translate(to='en')

    except TranslatorError(TextBlobError):
        word=" "  #replace word with space
        txt=txt+word
    except NotTranslated(TextBlobError):
         txt=txt+word+" "
    else:
         txt=txt+w+" "
print(txt)
```

I am getting the following errors:

```
except TranslatorError(TextBlobError): 
NameError: name 'TranslatorError' is not defined  

raise NotTranslated('Translation API returned the input string unchanged.')
textblob.exceptions.NotTranslated: Translation API returned the input string unchanged.
```

I referred to the following link:
https://textblob.readthedocs.io/en/dev/api_reference.html#textblob.exceptions.TextBlobError

I am not able to resolve these errors. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

> en_blob = TextBlob(u'Simple is better than complex.')
>   print(en_blob.translate(from_lang='en', to='es'))

Explicitly stating "from_lang".

Comment: P.S. I get an error when translating from english, to english using TextBlob. I created a statement stating if language to translate to !="en", then translate. Now, my code works perfectly...

Comment: Thanks. But what if textblob fails to translate? We need exception handling

Comment: What do you mean? 
Tbh I have decided to switch to pytranslator https://pypi.org/project/py-translator/
I believe they both use the google translate api, so the translation is identical to textblob.

Comment: from py_translator import Translator

Translator().translate(text="Hello world, my translation works", dest=new_lang).text

Comment: There are texts that Textblob is not able to translate. In that case, Textblob  throws exception. I have non-English words mixed with English text. I want, if Textblob is not able to translate then it just skip by replacing with " "(empty string) and move on for next non-English text

Comment: I know the error now - TextBlob uses Google's Translate API. If you make too many requests, Google Blocks your IP address from accessing their translate service, temporarily. Google gives you £200 free to access their API. Any other api is likely to use google, and they would have the same restrictions as far as I am aware of.

Comment: This bug is for when the translation works perfectly, and they all of a sudden you get a "json... cannot translate..." colorful display message.

Answer (score 0):

It is just because some words in both languages are the same. If we look at the documentation of TextBlob how it raises the exception:

The first it translates the word, so you call **translate** method, it looks like:

```
def translate(self, source, from_lang='auto', to_lang='en', host=None, type_=None):
    """Translate the source text from one language to another."""
    if PY2:
        source = source.encode('utf-8')
    data = {"q": source}
    url = u'{url}&sl={from_lang}&tl={to_lang}&hl={to_lang}&tk={tk}'.format(
        url=self.url,
        from_lang=from_lang,
        to_lang=to_lang,
        tk=_calculate_tk(source),
    )
    response = self._request(url, host=host, type_=type_, data=data)
    result = json.loads(response)
    if isinstance(result, list):
        try:
            result = result[0]  # ignore detected language
        except IndexError:
            pass
    self._validate_translation(source, result)
    return result
```

when as you can see the last second line, it tries to validates the translation. if the both translated and source are the same, then exception is thrown

```
def _validate_translation(self, source, result):
    """Validate API returned expected schema, and that the translated text
    is different than the original string.
    """
    if not result:
        raise NotTranslated('Translation API returned and empty response.')
    if PY2:
        result = result.encode('utf-8')
    if result.strip() == source.strip():
        raise NotTranslated('Translation API returned the input string unchanged.')
```

As Example, if you try to translate a word of "*Plauen*" from English to German, this is because the word *Plauen* are the same in English and German.

You can escape such exception simply with try and except block in Python.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The way error handling is done is not right, I used the below code and it worked, hope this helps.

```
import textblob.exceptions

txt=" "
for word in text.split():
    try:
        w=TextBlob(word)
        w=w.translate(to='en')

    except textblob.exceptions.TranslatorError:
        word=" "  #replace word with space
        txt=txt+word
    except textblob.exceptions.NotTranslated:
        txt=txt+word+" "
    else:
        txt=txt+w+" "
print(txt)
```