# Problem to translate with textblob in python - textblob.exceptions

Tags: python, anaconda, pypdf, textblob

I`m trying to extract text from a pdf using Pypdf2 and translate with Textblob.

```
import PyPDF2 as pdf
from docx import Document
from textblob import TextBlob

Arquivo = 'teste.pdf'
lgout = input('\nPara qual língua traduzir? ex: pt, en, es: ')
lgin = input('\nQual língua é o documento? ex: pt, en, es: ')

with open(Arquivo, mode='rb') as f:
    reader = pdf.PdfFileReader(f)
    npages = int(reader.numPages) -1

    ret = 0
    while ret <= npages:
        page = reader.getPage(ret)
        pagext = str(page.extractText())
        blob = TextBlob(pagext)
        text_trans = (blob.translate(from_lang=lgin,to = lgout))
        doc = Document()
        doc.add_paragraph(str(text_trans))
        doc.save('Doc teste' + str(ret) + '.docx')
        ret +=1
    else:
        print("Documento convertido")
```

But when I run the script I get the erro

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Pedrovhz/Desktop/Estudos/Python/Python Translator/tradutor_pdf.py", line 18, in <module>
    text_trans = (blob.translate(from_lang=lginout,to = lgoutpu))
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/textblob/blob.py", line 547, in translate
    from_lang=from_lang, to_lang=to))
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/textblob/translate.py", line 61, in translate
    self._validate_translation(source, result)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/textblob/translate.py", line 85, in _validate_translation
    raise NotTranslated('Translation API returned the input string unchanged.')
textblob.exceptions.NotTranslated: Translation API returned the input string unchanged.
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, thx for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look into this link [textblob.exceptions.NotTranslated: Translation API returned the input string unchanged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53900541/textblob-exceptions-nottranslated-translation-api-returned-the-input-string-unc)

As a workaround, you can either use a try-catch block or if-else by detecting the language and translate it. I have written a sample snippet

```
    if blob.detect_language() == 'es':
        translated = blob.translate(from_lang='es',to='en')
        print(translated)
    elif blob.detect_language() == 'de':
        translated = blob.translate(from_lang='de',to='en')
        print(translated)
    else:
        print("not translated")
```

Let me know if it doesn't works for you.